# Fixed, auto, and percentage height divs in CSS

Tags: html, css, wpf

How can I style the following divs:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="top"></div>
   <div id="middle"></div>
   <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

so that the first child div has a fixed height, say 200px, the second div has the height of its own children, and the last one spans across the rest of the screen? I have a span element inside the second div that could be of any length. All divs have 100% width.

UPDATE: Not sure why people downvoted this. I need something similar to the WPF Grid's layout:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You might want to look into [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), only really supported by modern browser though.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for :

```
<html>
<div style="height:200px;">
</div>
<div>
    <table width=100px height=100px border=1;><tr><td>test</td></tr></table>
</div>
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <table width=100% height=100% border=1;><tr><td>test</td></tr></table>
</div>
</html>
```